# Why there are multiple copies for the same version of gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have an android studio project, with the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` configured as following.

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

And I have the `2.2.1-all` version installed in my home directory.

```
.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/c64ydeuardnfqctvr1gm30w53/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

When I invoke `./gradlew` command to build the project. I should use the `gradle-2.2.1-all.zip` to build.

But it doesn't, it will download another gradle even for the same version instead. So, there are two gradles for the version `2.2.1-all`. Because my internet connection is very slow, it takes too long.

```
.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/c64ydeuardnfqctvr1gm30w53/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/6dibv5rcnnqlfbq9klf8imrndn/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

It's very annoying since it has to download a new one for the same version very time I invoke the command to build my project.

Why the gradle build system couldn't pick the installed one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I have multiple gradle wrapper distributions downloaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551540/why-do-i-have-multiple-gradle-wrapper-distributions-downloaded) ... still, yeah, annoying, unresolved(yet) problem ...

Comment: and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102319/how-can-a-specify-the-gradle-wrapper-download-location) ... i have checked one thing: GRADLE_USER_HOME is not defined when you run new console(cmd) ... maybe this is a problem

Answer (score 7):

The problem occurred is because the hash policy for the download url is different between studio's `gradle-wrapper.jar` and latest `gradle-wrapper.jar`.

The `gradle-wrapper.jar` under my Android app directory (I guess it's copied from `android-sdk-macosx/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`) use the following method to calculate hash for the download url.

```
// PathAssembler.java
private String getMd5Hash(String string) {
    try {
        MessageDigest e = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();
        e.update(bytes);
        return (new BigInteger(1, e.digest())).toString(32);
    } catch (Exception var4) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not hash input string.", var4);
    }
}
```

But the latest `gradle-wrapper.jar` use the following method to do. The radix change from `32` to `36`.

```
private String getHash(String string) {
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();
        messageDigest.update(bytes);
        return new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest()).toString(36);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not hash input string.", e);
    }
}
```

The magic string I found in the directory name is the md5 hash string of the download url.

For version 2.10, there is a directory name

`.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.10-all/a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst`

And the `a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst` is hashed from the download url.

```
try {
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    messageDigest.update("https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip".getBytes());
    System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest()).toString(36));
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By using the same hash method (use the same `gradle-wrapper.jar`) for  the same download url from `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, there won't be multiple downloads for the same version of gradle.

This issue only exist between android studio project and other gradle project.

Answer (score 1):

It's an Unresolved issue [Why Gradle download wrapper multiple times for the same version?](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3196)

Comment: This is not an anwer to the question. Please consider writing an own question instead, or commenting on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Saw same problem and made a try. Looks like that Android Studio does not build with the `grale/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` in your project, but instead the one within itself(`Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` in macOS).

As mentioned by @alijandro, if the `gradle-wrapper.jar` in your two projects are not using the same hash policy, or not the same as the Android Studio app, it will cause the problem you saw.

To get rid of this, just copy the `gradle-wrapper.jar` from Android Studio app directory to your project and you're all set.